# Passing options for headless chrome

Tags: pa11y

Is it possible to pass config options for browser launch?

Running into issues when trying to run continuous integration (CircleCi)

```
Launching Headless Chrome
Failed to launch chrome!
[0731/172545.445686:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, should be possible. The [chromeLaunchConfig object](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#chromelaunchconfig-object) in Pa11y's settings accepts Puppeteer config options, including `args`, which passes [Chromium flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to the headless browser itself.

I haven't tested it, but something like this should hopefully work in your Pa11y CI settings:

```
chromeLaunchConfig: {
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
}
```